# Cual es el proceso real de ejecucion de script de Python?

Tags: python

-La pregunta se prodria resumir a lo siguiente: cual es el proceso de ejecucion de un script de Python? (se espera que se mencionen conceptos como bytecode, CPython, ast, parser, etc ...)

Comment: Bienvenido a _mundo de la filosofía de la programación_. Lamentablemente, es una pregunta demasiado amplia (poliédrica) para contestarla aquí. Una buena contestación generaría más preguntas que respuestas responda. Pero, ya que has tenido contacto con el _bytecode_, mi recomendación es que te mires el [_AST_ (Árbol Astracto de Sintáxis)](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html?highlight=ast#module-ast). Es la primera etapa de la interpretación del código python, antes incluso de generar bytecode o ejecutar código.

Comment: Si quieres discutir de filosofía y esas cosas, te recomiendo visites el chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Answer (score 3):

Bueno como sabrás la mayoría de los lenguajes de programación son de alto nivel eso quiere decir que pueden ser *entendido por nosotros* ya que lo escribimos como código no será lo que la maquina lea, la maquina entiende un lenguaje de bajo nivel.

Existen 2 tipos de *programas* que hacen el trabajo de pasar el *código normal*, comúnmente llamado *código fuente* a un lenguaje de bajo nivel, estos son los *interpretes* y los *compiladores*, los cuales al final acaban leyendo texto plano, y aquí unas aclaraciones:

- De forma predeterminada, los archivos fuente de Python se tratan como codificados en UTF-8.
- No todos los interpretes y/o compiladores trabajan con la codificación UTF-8, mayormente es ASCII.

En un lenguaje compilado, un compilador traducirá el código fuente directamente a código binario de máquina. Este código de máquina es específico para esa máquina de destino. Después de la compilación, la máquina de destino ejecutará directamente el código de la máquina.

## El interprete

El intérprete, que es específico de la máquina de destino, traduce cada declaración del código fuente en *lenguaje de máquina*. Aquí otra aclaración

> - La única implementación de Python que tiene un JIT(just-in-time) es [PyPy](http://pypy.org/)
> - Python generalmente se denomina lenguaje interpretado, sin embargo, combina compilación e interpretación

**Nota**: Existe un compilador llamado [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) que lo que hace es compilar en **JIT**, esto para hacer la ejecución mas rápida, pues Python es rápido comparado con otros lenguajes interpretados pero no comparado con los compilados, exactamente por lo que se mencionó.

Como detalle, el interprete de Python tiene 2 modos, un *modo interactivo* y otro *no interactivo*, el *modo interactivo* es el que vez cuando ejecutas en la terminal el comando *python* y la *interfaz* cambia. El trabajo de Python, para leer, en este modo es diferente, las características para edición de líneas del intérprete incluyen edición interactiva, sustitución de historial, esto se hace gracias a la librería [GNU Readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html). Puedes leer mas sobre el *Modo interactivo* en la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode)

El trabajo del interprete de Python es traducir tu *código fuente* (que al final es texto plano para el interprete, codificado en algún estándar) y traducirlo a **Bytecodes** para que finalmente sea interpretado por la *Virtual Machine* (VM).

## Bytecode

EL *bytecode* es como un *lenguaje intermedio* entre el *código fuente* y el *código maquina*, primero se traduce el *código fuente* en *bytecodes* y después interpretan los *bytecodes* mediante un programa denominado máquina virtual.

#### Proceso

Cuando ejecutamos un código fuente (un archivo `.py`), Python primero lo compila en un bytecode (esta es representación de tu código fuente independiente de la plataforma de bajo nivel), sin embargo esto aun no es el  *código de máquina* en binario (0,1) y no puede ser ejecutado directamente por la máquina de destino. Este *Bytecode* solo puede ser leído y *ejecutado* por la *Virtual Machine*, como se explico mas arriba.

Luego del proceso de generado del *Bytecode*, este se envía a el *PVM* (*Python Virtual Manchine*), este es el encargado de interpretar el *Bytecode* para transformarlo al *lenguaje maquina* en binario (0, 1)

Pero en realidad pasa algo mas antes de convertir todo el código a *bytecodes*, te has dado cuenta de los mensajes cuando tienes algún error de sintaxis?, mas que seguro que si, peroo... ¿por que si hay un error en la linea 10 el error te lo tira al ejecutar el código?, no se supone que era un lenguaje interpretado, acaso no debería de leer linea por linea o bloque por bloque?.

Como dije antes el *código fuente* es texto plano para el interprete por lo que su primer trabajo será verificar que la sintaxis sea correcta, para eso Python utiliza un *Parser* (analizador sintáctico) pues este lee el archivo en busca de errores de sintaxis, ya que el interprete solo puede ejecutar código correctamente escrito por eso es que te sale el error de `SyntaxInvalid` o `SyntaxError` al ejecutar el programa y no te sale un `Index out of range` ya que este es un error en tiempo de ejecución que indica que el índice al que queremos acceder esta fuera de un rango especifico. Luego de este proceso viene el generado del *Bytecode* y se realiza todo lo que ya fue explicado con anterioridad.

## CPython

Primero hablemos un poco de la historia de Python, pues se utilizó el lenguaje de programación *C* para implementar la primera versión del lenguaje y esta decisión aún está vigente. Todos los *Pythons* que vienen del PSF([Python Software Foundation](https://www.python.org/psf-landing/)) están escritos en el lenguaje "C".
Algo que quiero aclarar es que `CPython != Cython`. CPython es la implementacion en *C* del interprete y por esta razón es que al final todo se resume a *C*, y es este el encargado de interpretar el bytecode generado.

Aquí te dejo un pequeño grafico del proceso, fue echo por @abulafia
[image: procesos_de_cpython]

**Aclaraciones**

- El bytecode es independiente de la plataforma, pero el *PVM* es específico de la máquina de destino. (x64, x86, etc)
- *CPython* compila el código fuente de Python en *bytecode*, y luego la máquina virtual *CPython* ejecuta este código de bytes.
- El *bytecode* generado se almacena en un archivo `.pyc`

Comment: 1. La máquina no _entiende_ ensablador, únicamente código máquina, que es binario (ceros y unos). El ensamblador es, ciertamente, un lenguaje de bajo nivel, pero es ya legible para humanos y no es lo mismo que el código máquina. Si escribes un programa en ensamblador, este no se le puede dar directamente al equipo, primero tiene que ser _ensamblado_, que es el proceso de convertirlo a código máquina que es lo único que la máquina es capaz de ejecutar.

Comment: 2. El código fuente no solo puede estar codificado en UTF8, diría que más del 90% del código fuente del mundo aún está y va a continuar en ASCII (7 bits).

Comment: 3. JIT lleva de apellido "compilation". Los interpretes generalmente no "interpretan cada línea de código en JIT", sino que _compilan_ las partes (usualmente varias líneas). Quizás hablas solo de python y quizás todos los interpretes de python lo hagan (lo desconozco), pero entonces habría que mejorar la redacción.

Comment: 4. Diría que se puede decir que el _bytecode_ es el código máquina, de la máquina virtual, que ya no lo _interpreta_, sino que lo _ejecuta_. Para ejecutarlo, necesariamente debe _traducir_ los códigos de operación que recibe en códigos de operación que pueda ejecutar el hardware real sobre el que se ejecuta la máquina virtual.  Pero la redacción es importante, ya que la máquina virtual no _interpreta_ el bytecode. (formalmente, no hay otro interprete a este nivel).

Comment: Si, la maquina lo único que entienende es código maquina el cual es binario y es un lenguaje de bajo nivel, creo que no explique muy bien eso

Comment: 2. Puse lo de utf por que python así lo dice en su documentación, ya que también se puede especificar otra

Comment: En cuanto a lo de JIT también lo desconozco un poco, y en lo del bytecode exactamente me refería a que la VM es quien ejecuta ese código, creo que si lo dije.

Comment: @Cristian, mis comentarios son para que consideres mejorar tu respuesta, Por ejemplo, hablando de UTF8, de nuevo, puede ser que quieras referirte solo a Python, en cuyo caso hay que mejorar la redacción, pues actualmente lo haces de manera general, si re-lees, hablas de interpretes y compiladores e que leen el texto plano _codificado en utf8_. Eso, dicho de esa manera, es incorrecto.  Como he dicho antes, lo más probable es que la gran mayoría del código fuente que leen compiladores e interpretes hoy día esté en codificación ASCII, y solo una pequeña porción en UTF8.

Comment: @jachguate estaria bien que publicaras una respuesta a la pregunta, se nota que tienes conocimientos en el tema.

Comment: @PySanti la pregunta fue cerrada, ya no se puede publicar respuestas, y gracias me hiciste acordar que aun no edito la respuesta, en un momento lo haré, aun estoy en mi cama :/

Comment: @Christian agrega algo sobre el proceso de conversion a bytecode, hasta ahora se que el proceso seria algo asi ... codigo fuente -> parser -> ast -> aquello que lo transforma en bytecode -> CPython -> ejecucion

Comment: @PySanti edite la respuesta explicando mejor los conceptos que jachguate me indico, en un momento añado la explicación que me pediste